# php call foreign function as internal method

Tags: php, oop

I wanna make a syntax like jquery in php, I wrote that class:

```
class events{

    public function auth($user, $pass, $callback){
        $status = 0;
        if($user and $pass){
            $status = 1;
        }
        call_user_func($callback, $status);
    }

    public function login(){
        echo "Welcome!";
    }

}

$events = new events;
$user = "u";
$pass = "p";
```

And that's Jquery like syntax:

```
/**
 * Jquery type callback function
 */
$events->auth($user, $pass, function($status){
    if($status){
        $this->login();
    }else{
        echo "Fail";
    }
});
```

Everything is OK except $this variable I used outer that class methods, I cannot use the callback function as a internal function for using $this into that function codes. 
Can I correct that error by changing something in my class ?

Comment: You can only use `$this` in classes.

Comment: I know that but I'm looking for a way to use $this in foreign functions which are calling by that class methods.

Comment: Why not call `$events->login()` instead of trying `$this->login()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind your anonymous function to the object with [`Closure::bind`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php).

---

#### Example:

```
class events{

    public function auth($user, $pass, $callback){
        $status = 0;
        if($user and $pass){
            $status = 1;
        }
        call_user_func(Closure::bind($callback, $this), $status);
    }

    public function login(){
        echo "Welcome!";
    }

}

$events = new events;
$user = "u";
$pass = "p";

$events->auth($user, $pass, function($status){
    if($status){
        $this->login();
    }else{
        echo "Fail";
    }
});
```

---

#### Output:

```
Welcome!
```

---

Also note that it's not necessary to use `call_user_func()`, you can replace that line with something like this if you prefer:

```
$callback = $callback->bindTo($this);
$callback($status);
```

Comment: can I use Closure::bind in auth function? for example:
 Closure::bind($callback($status));

Comment: Yes, but not like that, because you are actually calling the closure before creating the bound copy. You can do this: `$callback = Closure::bind($callback, $this); $callback($status);`
@Paul: please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: very very thanks @PaulCrovella and others for your great answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the instance of the class to the callback:

```
<?php
class events{

    public function auth($user, $pass, $callback){
        $status = 0;
        if($user and $pass){
            $status = 1;
        }
        $callback($status, $this);
    }

    public function login(){
        echo "Welcome!";
    }

}

$events = new events;
$user = "u";
$pass = "p";


/**
 * Jquery type callback function
 */
$events->auth($user, $pass, function($status, $self){
    if($status){
        $self->login();
    }else{
        echo "Fail";
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I would be interested in an explanation too. This should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to "bind" closures to specific objects like in JavaScript. The `$this` keyword cannot therefore be used outside of a class. However, since `$events` is the instance which `$this` would reference, you can do this:

```
$events->auth($user, $pass, function($status){
    if($status){
        $events->login();
    }else{
        echo "Fail";
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Apparently I was wrong, [there is a way](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) to bind closures to specific instances. See Paul's answer.